# How do I solve HTML Error 500 in Jsoup Java

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

i have two parts running perfectly fine. 
First I connect to the website and put my login name and password into the form.
I get the cookies and store them.

```
    Connection.Response login = Jsoup.connect("website")
                .data("name", "name")
                .data("password", "password")
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();
    Map<String, String> cookies = login.cookies();
```

this works just fine, even the next connect

```
     Document doc1 = Jsoup.connect("website/subpages")
                .cookies(cookies)
                .get();
```

doc1 is running perfect and I can get the text with:

```
      String pages1 = doc.toString();
```

but on my last request, I get Server Error 500

```
    Document pages2 = Jsoup.connect(website/anothersubpage)
                .cookies(cookies)
                .get();
```

I guess the Problem is that the last url "website/anothersubpage" is no set Url.
Each time I login and get a new Session Key (which is the Cookie I store in the Cookies) the URL to the subpage changes.

After I thought about it, I parsed the hole pages into an String and used substring to get the new variable URL.

```
 String newLink = text.substring(text.indexOf("Start href"),text.indexOf("End href"));
```

It worked, so I stored into the String newLink, the link (href"") from the website.
But now if I use the same code as before:

```
    Document pages2 = Jsoup.connect(my parsed href"..." link)
                .cookies(cookies)
                .get();
```

I get the error 500, I tried so much stuff but I can't get it to work for 3 days now.

I am really grateful for every suggestion or tip

Comment: Solving problems like this requires that you learn how to use tools like Wireshark and Telerik Fiddler to observe the traffic that occurs between your web browser and the website you're trying to scrape, so that you can *precisely mimic* the traffic in your own code.

Comment: You might look at the headers your browser is sending when you visit that page manually. It is possible that it looks for the `Referer` or other header, or at the `User-Agent` to tell that it's really a browser. The suggestion to use a tool like Fiddler is an excellent one.